# is it possible to distribute different version of app to different client by store, by Enterprise or B2B?

Tags: ios, app-store, enterprise, app-distribution

I have an app on store and all client are used it. Sometimes some client needs additional feature that isn't wanted by others so in that case I make AdHoc build for that particular client, but it is not proper solution.

I think on Enterprise solution but apple not allowed to distribute outside the organization in it and I have all users are clients.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has a user login, download a user specific configfile directly after login and check in code for feature availability by looking into it. Large companies like Spotify and also startups do it this way to test new features without releasing them to all.

Comment: My purpose is not testing but maintain different version of app for different client for long time. So i need a Place like store have all version of my app and client visit at there and download appropriate version.

Comment: What's wrong with it. You can use it for testing features and/or releasing features to specific clients. It doesn't matter. I think it's the best solution for your case. Make one app with everything inside and configure it depending by login for every person/group as you like. I already worked with several apps on same code base and it's a pain to handle. Sooner or later you combine it in one configurable app.